# Draw a circle without a texture

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sprite-kit

I'm creating a little game and i'm having many problems trying to draw a circle. I want to do it for osx, not for iOs.

Draw a rectangle is so easy using this code.

```
CGSize posBarraVida;
    posBarraVida.height = 10;
    posBarraVida.width = 100;
    SKSpriteNode* barraVida = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:posBarraVida];
    barraVida.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/8 + 50, self.size.height - 25.0f);
    barraVida.zPosition = 1;
    [self addChild:barraVida];
```

But i have this code to draw a circle but i'm having error trying to convert the path of the `NSBezierPath` to the `CGPathRef` property of the `SKShapeNode`.

```
CGRect box = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        NSBezierPath *circlePath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:box];

        SKShapeNode *circle = [SKShapeNode node];
        circle.path = circlePath.bezierPath;    // conversion error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `path` property on `SKShapeNode` is typed as `CGPathRef`. This is an indication that you need to use a CGPath object instead of an NSBezierPath object. In some cases, the Cocoa version of a class is toll-free bridged to the "core" version, but not in this case.

Instead, you'd want something like:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, rect);
circle.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
circle.path = circlePath.bezierPath.CGPath;
```

instead of

```
circle.path = circlePath.bezierPath;
```

I would prefer to use Bezier Path instead of `CGMutablePathRef` with Sprite Kit. Sometimes I get unexpected memory leaks with using `CGMutablePathRef` as a path for `SKPhysicsBody`

Comment: Sorry but your solution proposed throw an error for OSX, bezierPath doesn't exist for NSBezierPath class in OSX.

Comment: The `CGPath` property exists only for UIKit, not AppKit.